# Ruby Not Detecting Gems

Tags: ruby, rubygems, rvm, appfog

For some reason, Ruby can't seem to under stand that I installed the AppFog gem (`af`). When I run `af`, I get this:

```
/Users/myface13214/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p327/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/dependency.rb:247:in `to_specs': Could not find af (>= 0) amongst [Saikuro-1.1.0, actionmailer-3.2.8, actionpack-3.2.8, activemodel-3.2.8, activerecord-3.2.8, activeresource-3.2.8, activesupport-3.2.8, arel-3.0.2, awesome_print-1.1.0, bcrypt-ruby-3.0.1, bourbon-2.1.2, builder-3.0.4, cancan-1.6.8, capistrano-2.13.5, capybara-2.0.0, cgi_multipart_eof_fix-2.5.0, childprocess-0.3.6, chronic-0.3.0, chunky_png-1.2.6, churn-0.0.24, code_analyzer-0.3.0, coffee-rails-3.2.2, coffee-script-2.2.0, coffee-script-source-1.4.0, colored-1.2, compass-0.12.2, compass-rails-1.0.3, configatron-2.9.1, cover_me-1.2.0, daemons-1.1.9, daemons-1.0.10, devise-2.1.2, diff-lcs-1.1.3, erubis-2.7.0, excon-0.16.10, execjs-1.4.0, factory_girl-4.1.0, factory_girl_rails-4.1.0, fastthread-1.0.7, ffi-1.1.5, figaro-0.5.0, flay-1.4.3, flog-2.5.3, fssm-0.2.9, gem_plugin-0.2.3, hashie-1.2.0, highline-1.6.15, hike-1.2.1, hirb-0.7.0, i18n-0.6.1, journey-1.0.4, jquery-rails-2.1.3, json-1.7.5, json_pure-1.7.5, kgio-2.7.4, libwebsocket-0.1.6, mail-2.4.4, main-4.7.1, metric_fu-2.1.1, metrical-0.1.0, mime-types-1.19, mongrel-1.2.0.pre2, multi_json-1.3.7, net-scp-1.0.4, net-sftp-2.0.5, net-ssh-2.6.1, net-ssh-gateway-1.1.0, nokogiri-1.5.5, orm_adapter-0.4.0, polyglot-0.3.3, progressbar-0.11.0, rack-1.4.1, rack-cache-1.2, rack-ssl-1.3.2, rack-test-0.6.2, rails-3.2.8, rails_best_practices-1.12.0, railties-3.2.8, raindrops-0.10.0, rake-10.0.1, rcov-0.9.11, rdoc-3.12, reek-1.2.12, ripper_ruby_parser-0.0.8, roodi-2.1.0, rspec-core-2.12.0, rspec-expectations-2.12.0, rspec-mocks-2.12.0, rspec-rails-2.12.0, ruby2ruby-1.2.5, ruby_parser-2.3.1, rubyzip-0.9.9, sass-3.2.3, sass-rails-3.2.5, selenium-webdriver-2.26.0, sexp_processor-3.2.0, sprockets-2.1.3, sqlite3-1.3.6, syntax-1.0.0, thor-0.16.0, tilt-1.3.3, treetop-1.4.12, tzinfo-0.3.35, uglifier-1.3.0, unicorn-4.4.0, vcr-2.3.0, warden-1.2.1, websocket-1.0.2, xpath-1.0.0, yamler-0.1.0] (Gem::LoadError)
    from /Users/myface13214/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p327/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/dependency.rb:256:in `to_spec'
    from /Users/myface13214/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p327/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems.rb:1231:in `gem'
    from /Users/myface13214/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327/bin/af:18:in `<main>'
    from /Users/myface13214/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327/bin/ruby_noexec_wrapper:14:in `eval'
    from /Users/myface13214/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327/bin/ruby_noexec_wrapper:14:in `<main>'
```

This is even after installing it. For some reason `gem install` won't install it.
If it helps, I'm running 1.9.3 installed through RVM.

Comment: Are you using bash or zsh?  What version?  Still missing information to try to duplicate this problem.

Comment: @vgoff ZSH with Oh MY ZSH. ZSH version 4.3.9.

Comment: Still waiting for you to edit the question with some of the information I showed, to see if maybe we can spot something.  Perhaps the output from `rvm info`.  Did you also attempt this using `bundle exec` at all?

Comment: I think it is the same issue shown here [Gem executables not showing up with ohmyzsh](http://superuser.com/questions/495465/gem-binaries-not-found-with-oh-my-zsh) unless they use bundle exec (I hinted at this earlier).

Answer (score 11):

You didn't really show what you were using it with, so I am going to outline some troubleshooting and installation steps that I have used to install this.  A clean `gemset`, the latest `rvm`, and recording it as I do it to post here.

The first thing you will want to confirm is your `rvm` environment.  I did these two steps:

```
$: rvm get head
$: rvm use 1.9.3-p327
```

And then:

```
$: rvm info
```

which finally gives me this report:

```
ruby-1.9.3-p327@CleanProject:

  system:
    uname:       "Linux lazurus 3.2.0-32-generic #51-Ubuntu SMP Wed Sep 26 21:32:50 UTC 2012 i686 i686 i386 GNU/Linux"
    system:      "debian/wheezy_sid/i386"
    bash:        "/bin/bash => GNU bash, version 4.2.24(1)-release (i686-pc-linux-gnu)"
    zsh:         " => not installed"

  rvm:
    version:      "rvm 1.16.20 (master) by Wayne E. Seguin <wayneeseguin@gmail.com>, Michal Papis <mpapis@gmail.com> [https://rvm.io/]"
    updated:      "13 minutes 59 seconds ago"

  ruby:
    interpreter:  "ruby"
    version:      "1.9.3p327"
    date:         "2012-11-10"
    platform:     "i686-linux"
    patchlevel:   "2012-11-10 revision 37606"
    full_version: "ruby 1.9.3p327 (2012-11-10 revision 37606) [i686-linux]"

  homes:
    gem:          "/home/some_user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327@CleanProject"
    ruby:         "/home/some_user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p327"

  binaries:
    ruby:         "/home/some_user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p327/bin/ruby"
    irb:          "/home/some_user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p327/bin/irb"
    gem:          "/home/some_user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p327/bin/gem"
    rake:         "/home/some_user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327@global/bin/rake"

  environment:
    PATH:         "/home/some_user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327@CleanProject/bin:/home/some_user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327@global/bin:/home/some_user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p327/bin:/home/some_user/.rvm/bin:/usr/local/heroku/bin:/home/some_user/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/lib/jvm/java-6-sun/bin"
    GEM_HOME:     "/home/some_user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327@CleanProject"
    GEM_PATH:     "/home/some_user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327@CleanProject:/home/some_user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327@global"
    MY_RUBY_HOME: "/home/some_user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p327"
    IRBRC:        "/home/some_user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p327/.irbrc"
    RUBYOPT:      ""
    gemset:       "CleanProject"
```

I have a clean gemset, no `Gemfile` so no `bundle install`.  Simply this:

```
 $: gem install af --no-rdoc --no-ri       
Fetching: json_pure-1.6.7.gem (100%)       
Fetching: rubyzip-0.9.9.gem (100%)         
Fetching: mime-types-1.19.gem (100%)       
Fetching: rest-client-1.6.7.gem (100%)     
Fetching: terminal-table-1.4.5.gem (100%)  
Fetching: interact-0.4.8.gem (100%)        
Fetching: addressable-2.2.8.gem (100%)     
Fetching: uuidtools-2.1.3.gem (100%)       
Fetching: rb-readline-0.4.2.gem (100%)     
Fetching: af-0.3.18.11.gem (100%)          
Successfully installed json_pure-1.6.7     
Successfully installed rubyzip-0.9.9       
Successfully installed mime-types-1.19     
Successfully installed rest-client-1.6.7   
Successfully installed terminal-table-1.4.5
Successfully installed interact-0.4.8      
Successfully installed addressable-2.2.8   
Successfully installed uuidtools-2.1.3     
Successfully installed rb-readline-0.4.2   
Successfully installed af-0.3.18.11        
10 gems installed
```

Then I check for the gems binary, so that I know it installs it.

```
$: which af
/home/some_user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327@CleanProject/bin/af
```

And when I do an directory listing:

```
$: ls /home/some_user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327@CleanProject/bin/
af
restclient
```

This is where it seems yours breaks...

```
 $: af
Usage: af [options] command [<args>] [command_options]
Try 'af help [command]' or 'af help options' for more information.
```

And further, I can run the help option:

```
$: af help
```

I get the help screen

```
Usage: af [options] command [<args>] [command_options]
Try 'af help [command]' or 'af help options' for more information.

Currently available af commands are:

  Getting Started
    target [url]                                 Reports current target or sets a new 

|
|  quite a few lines cut out for brevity's sake
|    

  Help
    help [command]                               Get general help or help on a specific command
    help options                                 Get help on available options
```

Of course, when I check the folders that are reflected in the rvm info, I see the `af` binary alongside the others.

Comment: For some reason, `which` shows the path, but running the `af` command returns the error.

Comment: There is a TODO listed in line 240 of dependency.rb that hints at a possible issue.  Are you using Bundler and any other gems?

Comment: Actually, I can see you are using bundler, I should have asked if you are doing `bundle exec af`.

Comment: `rvm get head` helped as it displayed there was an error by me having a ~/.gemrc file. Thanks!

Comment: I had to uninstall and reinstall the gem that it couldn't find after this, and it worked. So thanks :)

Answer (score 4):

Sometimes `rvm` may not be fully engaged which means your `$GEM_PATH` environment variable is not set correctly. Typically `rvm use 1.9.3` will fix that.

It may be that your `rvm` install is out of date or needs to be adjusted so that your default Ruby is set correctly.

Answer (score 3):

please do the following, in the project root:

`rvm use 1.9.3`

`rvm gemset create your-project-name`

`rvm gemset use your-project-name`

`bundle install`

And see if everything s working as expected.

Comment: Did the bundle install succeeded?

Comment: Yes, but none of the gems install